# Getting the map Image from the Here Map Rest API

Tags: here-api

I am trying to get the image of the map from waypoint0 to waypoint1 through the here map REST API.

This is the Request URL:

```
http://image.maps.cit.api.here.com/mia/1.6/routing?waypoint0=:waypoint0lat%2C:waypoint0lng&waypoint1=:waypoint1lat%2C:waypoint1lng&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Adisabled&app_id=:app_id&app_code=:app_code&lc=1652B4&lw=6&t=0&ppi=320&w=400&h=600
```

with

```
waypoint0lat: "40.7369182",
waypoint0lng: "-73.9885248",
waypoint1lat: "40.7051079",
waypoint1lng: "-74.0157525"
```

The response I get is a large object with numbers and unknown characters. How can I decipher this response into the image?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the link to API documentation. Can't find routing in image api.https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/map-image/basic-map-image

Comment: Yep. Here's the link: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-image/topics/examples-routing-chicago-pois.html

Comment: I checked the api, it returns you an image with route between waypoints plotted.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it did. I mistakenly thought I needed to make a request through the API to get the image of the map, but looks like I can just use the URL given. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the map image by using the example request from 
https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-image/topics/examples-routing-chicago-pois.html

Use your coordinates in the same example and an image tag should be able to render it on the webpage for you.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <img src="http://image.maps.cit.api.here.com/mia/1.6/routing
?app_id={YOURAPPID}
&app_code={YOURAPPCODE}
&waypoint0=40.7369182,-73.9885248
&waypoint1=40.7051079,-74.0157525
&poix0=40.7499714,-73.9979574;00a3f2;00a3f2;11;.
&poix1=40.7456827,-73.9954344;white;white;11;.
&lc=1652B4
&lw=6
&t=0
&ppi=320
&w=400
&h=600
"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Rendered using the demo app id ,app code

[image]

Comment: How to save this image file or convert it to base64 ?