How to retrieve images from HERE API preserving geometry
I tried https://image.maps.hereapi.com/mia/v3/ to extract images and I did successfully but they always come in the fashion (I guess) base64 format with no geometry. I'm a newbie in the use of apis so I guess I'm missing something.
BTW the /info endpoint of such api does not work.
Any guess?

Your question is incomplete because you show no code and your URL doesn't work so we can't test it. Please click [edit] and improve it. Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/33657295/2836621
